# Fractions that have interesting, fun or noteworthy decimal expansions

Tags: soft-question, rational-numbers

I'm looking to discover more fractions that have interesting* decimal expansions. (I'm asking out of curiosity, there is no particular academic reason as far as I'm concerned).

Here are a few examples:

$\dfrac{1}{99}=0.010101\dots$

$\dfrac{1}{999}=0.001001001\dots$

(and so on...)

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90690/interesting-pattern-in-the-decimal-expansion-of-frac1243) talks about:

$\dfrac{1}{243}=0.\overline{004115226337448559670781893}$

[This Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daro6K6mym8) talks about how:

$\frac{1}{999^2}=0.00000100200300400500600...$

'generates' the 3-digit integers (except $998$). Similar patterns arise with $1/99$, $1/9999$, and so on.

*I realize that 'interesting, fun or noteworthy' might make this question a bit open-ended or subjective, hence the 'soft-question' tag. Then again, I find it difficult to be more specific about what I'm looking for.

Comment: I’m not sure what you find interesting, but I’ve always been fascinated by how $\frac{1}{7}=0.\overline{142857}$, and the other sevenths have the same 6 numbers repeating, in the same order, but just starting at a different number. For example, $\frac{2}{7}=0.\overline{285714}$

Comment: You also have $1/9^2=0.0123456\ldots$ (all the single digits except $8$) and $1/99^2 =0.00010203040506\ldots$ (can you guess the missing double digit?)

Answer (score 3):

Given any repeating decimal expansion, you can find the rational number that generates it. For example, let's say I think that $.\overline{02040608}$ is interesting, then there is a process of calculating the corresponding fraction:
$$x = .\overline{02040608}$$
$$10^8x = 2040608.\overline{02040608}$$
$$10^8x - 2040608 = x$$
$$x = \frac{2040608}{10^8-1}.$$
You can generate any periodic decimal expansion you want via this method.

Edit: This method also illuminates why we see stuff like 99, 999, 9999 so much in these `interesting' decimal expansions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess 1/7 is probably the canonical example here.  Taking multiples cycles the digits in the decimal expansion.

[Here's something I wrote previously](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-number-142857-have-such-interesting-properties/answer/Daniel-McLaury) that goes into considerably more detail on the topic. To excerpt part of it:

> 1/7 = 0.142857142857142857...
>
> Multiplying by ten, we see that
>
> 10 * 1/7 = 1.42857 142857 142857...
>
> On the other hand, 10 * 1/7 = 10/7 = 1 + 3/7, so
>
> 1 + 3/7 = 1.42857142857142857...
>
> Subtracting 1 from each side, we have
>
> 3/7 = 0.42857142857142857...
>
> If we multiply by 100 instead of ten, 14 + 2/7 = 100 * 1/7 = 
>   14.2857142857142857... so 2/7 = .2857142857142857...
>
> Continuing with this game, we have
>
> 142 + 6/7 = 1000/7 = 142.857142857142857... so 6/7 =
>   0.857142857142857...
>
> 1428 + 4/7 = 10000/7 = 1428.57142857142857... so 4/7 =
>   0.57142857142857...
>
> 14285 + 5/7 = 100000/7 = 14285.7142857142857... so 5/7 =
>   0.7142857142857...
>
> so we see that the decimal expansions of each of 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, 4/7,
>   5/7, and 6/7 are cycles of the same digits.
>
> So what were the ingredients here?
>
> - 1/7 is a rational number with lowest-common-terms denominator
>     relatively prime to ten, so we get a repeating decimal that repeats
>     right off the bat.
> - By successively multiplying 1/7 by powers of ten,
>     we get all numbers whose fractional parts cover every multiple of 1/7
>     between 0 and 1.

The rest of the discussion goes on to characterize such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The number $$1/89 = 0.0112359550561798\ldots$$ is interesting as the digits form the Fibonacci sequence $1,1,2,3,5, 8, 13, 21,$... at least for a while.  If you want more terms of the sequence you can use, e.g.,

$$1/9899 = 0.000101020305081321\ldots$$

which gives you the two-digit Fibonacci numbers or

$$1 / 998999 = 0.000001001002003005\ldots$$

which gives you the three-digit Fibonacci numbers.

Why does this happen? I cannot tell you; it is a secret you must discover yourself...